# ¿Porque el constructor de Iterador me tira un error de incopatibilidad?

Tags: c++, template

Tengo una lista generica hecha con templates y tengo que usar un iterador para recorrerla
adjunto partes de la clase lista generica, aclaro de una vez que no puedo usar la list de la stl ni ningun iterador que exista en c++ ya hecho

```
#pragma once
#include "NodoGenerico.h"
#include "Iterador.h"
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
class ListaGenerica {
private:
    NodoGenerico<T>* primero;
    NodoGenerico<T>* actual;

public:

    ListaGenerica();
    ~ListaGenerica();

    void insertarNodo(NodoGenerico<T>* dato);
    NodoGenerico<T>* getPrimero();
    Iterador<T>* getIterador();
    void desligaPunteros();
    std::string toStringLista();
    int getCantidadObs();
};
template <typename T>
ListaGenerica<T>::ListaGenerica() {
    primero = nullptr;
    actual = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
ListaGenerica<T>::~ListaGenerica() {
    while (primero != nullptr) {
        actual = primero->getSiguiente();
        delete primero;
        primero = actual;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void ListaGenerica<T>::insertarNodo(NodoGenerico<T>* Pdato) {
    if (primero == nullptr) {
        primero = Pdato;
        primero->setSiguiente(nullptr);
    }
    else
    {
        actual = primero;
        while (actual->getSiguiente() != nullptr) {
            actual = actual->getSiguiente();
        }
        actual->setSiguiente(Pdato);
    }
}


template <typename T>
inline NodoGenerico<T>* ListaGenerica<T>::getPrimero() {
    return primero;
}

template <typename T>
inline Iterador<T>* ListaGenerica<T>::getIterador() {
    return new Iterador<T>(this);
}


///precaucion/caution este metodo se usa en listas que no tengan que borrar los datos que almacenan, un mal uso provocaria fugas de memoria 
template <typename T>
void ListaGenerica<T>::desligaPunteros() {//metodo que sirve para desligar los punteros de los nodos a los objetos que apuntan(Desliga T* dato)
    actual = primero;
    while (actual != nullptr) {
        actual->setDato(nullptr);
        actual = actual->getSiguiente();
    }
}

template <typename T>
std::string ListaGenerica<T>::toStringLista() {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << "Los datos de la lista son: \n";
    Iterador<T>* iterador = getIterador();
    int i = 0;
    while (iterador->masObs()) {
        i++;
        s << i << "\n";
        s << *iterador->getSiguienteDato();
    }
    return s.str();
}

template <typename T>
int ListaGenerica<T>::getCantidadObs() {
    actual = primero;
    int i = 0;
    while (actual != nullptr) {
        i++;
        actual = actual->getSiguiente();
    }
    return i;
}
```

la clase lista funciona bien no he tenido problema con ella, el problema es cuando trato de hacer el iterador, abjunto el codigo del iterador(este esta pensado igual para funcionar con listas genericas hechas con templates)

```
#pragma once
#include "ListaGenerica.h"

template <typename T>
class Iterador {
private:
    ListaGenerica<T>* listaReferencia;
    NodoGenerico<T>* actual;

public:

    Iterador(ListaGenerica<T>*);
    ~Iterador();
    bool masObs();
    T* getSiguienteDato();

};


template<typename T>
inline Iterador<T>::Iterador(ListaGenerica<T>* listaExt)
{
    listaReferencia = listaExt;
    actual = listaReferencia->getPrimero();
}

template <typename T>
inline Iterador<T>::~Iterador() {
    listaReferencia = nullptr;
    actual = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
inline bool Iterador<T>::masObs() {
    return actual != nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
inline T* Iterador<T>::getSiguienteDato() {
    T* dato = nullptr;
    if (masObs()) {
        dato = actual->getDato();
        actual = actual->getSiguiente();
    }
    return dato;
}
```

El compilador me tira muchos errores pero creo uno de los mas importantes es el E0147 que me dice que la declaracion es imcompatible Iterador::Iterador(*).
Tambien el error C7550 'Iterador::Iterador': the qualified name in this context names a contructor, not a type
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Son muchos errores por eso puse una imagen, si necesitan mas me dicen, al principio no queria subir todo el codigo por ser un proyecto pero ya que, igualmente pongo la clase NodoGenerico, tambien algo a resaltar esque probre usando el iterador en vez de mandarle una lista ListaGenerica* le mande un NodoGenerico* con sus respectivas modificaciones al codigo del iterador y funciono perfertamente.

```
#pragma once
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>

class NodoGenerico {
private:
    T* dato;
    NodoGenerico<T>* siguiente;

public:

    NodoGenerico(T* Dato);
    ~NodoGenerico();
    NodoGenerico<T>* getSiguiente();
    void setSiguiente(NodoGenerico<T>*);
    void setDato(T* Dato);
    T* getDato();


};

template <typename T>
NodoGenerico<T>::NodoGenerico(T* Pdato) {
    dato = Pdato;
    siguiente = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
NodoGenerico<T>::~NodoGenerico() {
    if (dato != nullptr) {
        delete dato;
    }
    dato = nullptr;
    siguiente = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
NodoGenerico<T>* NodoGenerico<T>::getSiguiente() {
    return siguiente;
}

template<typename T>
void NodoGenerico<T>::setSiguiente(NodoGenerico<T>* Psiguiente) {
    siguiente = Psiguiente;
}

template<typename T>
T* NodoGenerico<T>::getDato() {
    return dato;
}

template<typename T>
void NodoGenerico<T>::setDato(T* Dato) {
    dato = Dato;
}
```

Comment: ¿No crees que tener que escribir todo esto: `lista.insertarNodo(new NodoGenerico<int>(new int{5}));` es demasiado? Cuando simplemente podrías hacer que el código necesario sea: `lista.insertar(5)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un problema de dependencia circular, agrega en cada archivo `.h` los preprocesadores `#ifndef, #define #endif`

En el header `ListaGenerica.h` vas a tener un problema aún así.
En lugar de incluir `Iterador.h`, usa "fordward declaration", basicamente declara la clase `Iterador` usando `class`:

```
#ifndef LISTAGENERICA_H
#define LISTAGENERICA_H

template<typename T>
class Iterador;

#include "NodoGenerico.h"
#include <sstream>
```

Desconozco si tienes limitaciones impuestas al hacer tu proyecto, pero personalmente organizaría el código para evitar que un archivo "A" incluya un archivo "B" y a su vez "B" incluya "A", ya que puede dar problemas en ciertos casos.
Lo que te comento lo he probado con el siguiente `main.cpp`

```
#include "ListaGenerica.h"
#include "NodoGenerico.h"
#include "Iterador.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ListaGenerica<int> lista;
    NodoGenerico<int>* nodo1 = new NodoGenerico<int>(new int(1));
    NodoGenerico<int>* nodo2 = new NodoGenerico<int>(new int(2));
    NodoGenerico<int>* nodo3 = new NodoGenerico<int>(new int(3));
    lista.insertarNodo(nodo1);
    lista.insertarNodo(nodo2);
    lista.insertarNodo(nodo3);

    cout << lista.toStringLista() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Y como detalle sin importancia, la función `toStringLista()` da mal indentado el output, puedes simplemente cambiar el salto de linea:

```
template <typename T>
std::string ListaGenerica<T>::toStringLista() {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << "Los datos de la lista son: \n";
    Iterador<T>* iterador = getIterador();
    int i = 0;
    while (iterador->masObs()) {
        i++;
        s << i << ": ";
        s << *iterador->getSiguienteDato() << "\n";
    }
    return s.str();
}
```

Comment: Lo primero que mencionas no es cierto. Ese es el propósito de la instrucción `#pragma once`.

Comment: efectivamente, el proposito de #pragma once es evitar la inclusion multiple de un archivo, pero por si solo no te resuelve la dependencia circular. Si un archivo A incluye B y B incluye A, el compilador tiene que procesar los archivos en orden y provoca conflictos y errores. Si el compilador procesa A.hpp primero, incluye B.hpp pero cuando procese B.hpp no puede incluir A.hpp, asi que "evita la dependencia circular" al no incluir el archivo pero te va a dar errores de que no encuentra las declaraciones de A.hpp precisamente porque tienes dependencia circular.